# Nexus Sonatype OSS curl or wget

Tags: curl, wget, nexus, sonatype

is it possible to download all repo folder with curl or wget?.
i can do it like individual,
curl -X GET -u user:pass http://IP:8081/repository/somefile.xx -O
but there are hundreds plus and it is updated every week.

Comment: links=$(curl -u user:pass -X GET 'http://IP:8081/service/rest/v1/search/assets?repository=test&group=' | grep downloadUrl | cut -d ":" -f 2-4 | cut -d "," -f1 | cut -d'"' -f 2)

for link in $links; do
    curl -X GET -u user:pass http://IP:8081/repository/test/rpm/3.0.0/${link} -O
done

Answer (score 0):

If `http://10.20.42.52:8081/repository` provide listing of files, then you might harness `--recursive` option of `wget` as follows

```
wget --user=user --password=pass --recursive -np -nc http://10.20.42.52:8081/repository
```

Explanation: `--recursive` does get links present in file available under given URL download them, get links present in that donwloads, download them and so on, `-np` get only files below in hierarchy (for example if `http://10.20.42.52:8081/repository` contains link to `http://10.20.42.52:8081` it will not be downloaded), `-nc` do not download if file is already present locally. Read [`wget` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html) if you want to know more about mentioned options.

Disclaimer: code is not tested as I do not have access to `http://10.20.42.52:8081/repository`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a write little shell script it is taken from assets like this page:
https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/assets-api
and then with a for loop is automatically download all rpms. Thanks to your answer.